# Is there a way to pass extra params to fullcalendar select callback?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-3, fullcalendar-2

I am using fullcalendar library for the calendar feature. The problem I am facing currently is to pass extra argument to 'select' callback.

```
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('select', new_start_date, new_end_date);
```

I am having trouble passing in extra params from the above 'select' callback. Is there a workaround to this?

Desired soln:

```
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('select', new_start_date, new_end_date, extraParam={date: "test"});
```

So that I can check the value passed in extra params too.

Comment: no, because it's fullCalendar which calls this function. This happens within the fullCalendar source code, which you can't (or at least shouldn't) really modify. That code doesn't know that you want to pass extra parameters, and anyway you've got no way to tell it what exact value to pass in any given circumstance. What is your extra parameter for, and where does it come from? Possibly you just need to declare it at a higher level so that it's still in scope when the callback runs, and then you can just use it as-is.

Comment: Also this is not how you set the callback. You have to supply a _function_ to it, not just a list of parameters. Otherwise there is nothing for fullCalendar to execute. Unless you are referring to the select _method_ (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/select_method/)? In which case the answer is still no.  Sure you could pass another parameter to it, but fullCalendar will ignore it because it's not expecting it, does not know what it represents, and has no code to handle it.

Comment: Perhaps if you explain what you are actually trying to achieve in a broader sense then we can find a solution to your problem.

Comment: @ADyson I tried with the above mentioned way by passing the extra params, It is working fine now. But like you mentioned I do not think it is correct way to work with fullcalendar functions.